# C: Example of unsafe of function pointer compare to delegate of C#

Tags: c#, c, delegates, function-pointers

When I learn delegate of C#, my book said that delegate same with function pointer in C, but more safer. After I read that line, I think : Ah, so C Compiler will not check prototype where the function pointer points to. And I'm totally wrong.

```
int add(int a, int b){ return a + b; }
float add_f(float a, float b){ return a + b; }

int (*f)(int,int);
f = add; // no compile-error
f = add_f; //compile-error
```

So, Please tell me why, and give me some examples to prove that C function pointer is unsafe when compare to delegate in C#, please.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, function pointers are type-safe.  You have to do something spectacularly stupid to break them (generally involving casting, unions, `memcpy`, or similar; it can't happen by accident).

In C, though, function types aren't nearly as strict.  You can do things like this:

```
int add(int a, int b){ return a + b; }
int add_f(float a, float b){ return a + b; }

int (*f)(); // empty argument list does NOT mean zero arguments.
            // for zero arguments, say int (*)(void)
f = &add;
f = &add_f;
```

http://ideone.com/Y6mCc

---

I was asked for an example of spectacularly stupid.  [Here goes](http://ideone.com/Z8Ryv):

```
#include <iostream>

int add(int a, int b){ return a + b; }
int add_f(float a, float b){ return a + b; }

union {
    int (*f1)(int, int);
    int (*f2)(float, float);
} fp;

int main(void)
{
    fp.f1 = &add;
    std::cout << "Expected (1): " << add(1, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Actual   (1): " << (fp.f1)(1, 3) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Expected (2): " << add(1.0f, 3.0f) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Actual   (2): " << (fp.f2)(1.0f, 3.0f) << std::endl;

    fp.f2 = &add_f;
    std::cout << "Expected (3): " << add_f(1.0f, 3.0f) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Actual   (3): " << (fp.f2)(1.0f, 3.0f) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Expected (4): " << add_f(1, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Actual   (4): " << (fp.f1)(1, 3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this foolishness is equally possible in C# with `Marshal.Copy`.

Comment: Oh. awesome ! :D  1) Can you give more examples about `memcpy` and some type of stupid casting please. Thanks :)

Comment: @hqt: You know those work in C# too, so they aren't really examples of C++ function pointers being less type-safe than C# delegates, right?

Comment: @Ben Can't find a reference to `Marshal.BlockCopy` (probably meant copy or something), but since the whole point of the Marshal class is using unmanaged code that is outside of C#'s language rules, I don't think that's a good example of why *c#* is unsafe. That's like saying Java is unsafe because you can invoke C code that can trample all over the memory space.

Comment: @Voo: Sorry, it's `Marshal.Copy` and/or `Buffer.BlockCopy`.  Yes, it bypasses the type checker, which is spectacularly stupid to combine with delegates.  That's the point.  So do casts, unions, and `memcpy` in C++; you'd be crazy to use those on function pointers.  (The one place a function pointer cast is needed is `GetProcAddress`/`dlsym`, but p/invoke will happily create a delegate of the wrong type also, if you get the signature wrong)

Comment: nice post and nice commment :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't take what every book says for its face value: the similarities between function pointers of C and delegates of C# are rather superficial. Comparing them feature-to-feature would produce a laundry list of differences, and the "safety" will be far from the top of that list.

The biggest safety problem with emulating C# delegates using function pointers is the ownership of data on which a function pointer operates. Recall that delegates are not restricted to static functions: you can produce a delegate from a member function, in which case the object becomes "embedded" in the delegate. There is no similar functionality in C: you need to do a lot of work in order to "bind" a function pointer to a piece of data. If the data becomes unavailable at some later point, and the function tries to use that data, it may trigger a crash. But that difference is an attribute of garbage-collected vs. manually managed memory environments.